# CSS - sticky table headers

Tags: html, css

I have a code pen here  - [Code](http://%20https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWaNdQ)

It's a table in a container, the table is bigger than the container.

When scrolling left to right the table and the headers move

When scrolling up and down I need the header to be sticky and the content to move underneath.

It sort of works here - [Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLaqLz)

but I lose the widths of the columns and the table.

How do I make the headers sticky but keep the width of the table

```
body{
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.page{
  background: white;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.table-con{
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
} 

table{
  /*table-layout: fixed;*/
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  width: 1500px;
}

thead th:first-child{
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

thead th{
  text-align: left;
}

thead tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

tbody td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child){
  background: yellow;
}

tbody td:first-child{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

th, td{
  padding: 10px 5px;

   &:first-of-type{
    padding-left: 20px;
  }

  &:last-of-type{
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz datatables doesnt do fixed header + fixed column, you can check their plugin compatibility log before commenting

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please refer below code hope it will helpful to you.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```